# Heroku Push rejected, Invalid add-on specification. Buildpacks must inform addons as a string

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Heroku is erroring out when I try to push. I'm using Flask and my only add-on is MongoHQ. Tried googling around and it looks like nobody's ever gotten this error before. Anyone know what's going on?

```
(virt1)daddy@thomass-mbp-2{~/helloflask}: git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.36 KiB, done.
Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detectedenter code here
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.6.
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.6)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.4)
       Cleaning up...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 33.2MB
-----> Launching...
 !     Push rejected, Invalid add-on specification.
       Buildpacks must inform addons as a string.

To git@heroku.com:nader-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:nader-app.git'
```

Comment: See also [Push rejected, Invalid add-on specification. Buildpacks must inform addons as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800071/push-rejected-invalid-add-on-specification-buildpacks-must-inform-addons-as-a).

Comment: Are you still having this issue @Nader?

Comment: While the canned text in the close reason suggests issues like typos, it also applies to issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that this was a problem at [Heroku](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/604):

> #### Error when deploying certain apps
>
> #### Resolved
>
> This change was reverted at 7:26 PM PDT (02:26 UTC).
>
> Posted about 11 hours ago, Apr 1, 2014 19:26 UTC
>
> #### Issue
>
> At 5:16 PM PDT (00:16 UTC), we deployed a change which validated the list of add-ons being returned from buildpacks. Buildpacks failing this validation would fail with the following error:
>
> ```
> Invalid add-on specification. Buildpacks must inform addons as a string.
> ```
>
> This impacted some of our own buildpacks, such as Python, Clojure, and PHP, when these buildpacks did not specify any add-ons to install.
>
> Posted about 13 hours ago, Apr 1, 2014 17:16 UTC

If you're having network problems with Heroku again in the future, one of the first things that you should check is the [Heroku Status](https://status.heroku.com/) page.